# ExtJS4: Passing parameters / properties from Treestore to Controller

Tags: extjs, parameters, extjs4, store

I´m using a simple TreeStore without proxies for building my Menu. Here is a simple Example:

**Store:**

```
Ext.define('LT.store.MnuApplication', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
            text: "Lists", 
            expanded: true, 
            children: [{
                text: "Countries", 
                leaf: true,
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

In the controller I´ve added a listener to the "click" event:

**Controller:**

```
init: function() {

        this.control({

            /**
             * Catch the treepanels in the menu accordion
             */
            'menu-main treepanel': {

                itemclick: function (view, record, item, index, event){

                    var clickedMnuNode = record;
                    var tabPanel = this.getTabPanel();                   

                    // Open tab only if the menu node is a leaf node
                    if (clickedMnuNode.isLeaf()) {
                        tabPanel.add({
                            xtype: clickedMnuNode.raw.loadTabComponent
                        }).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        this.callParent();

    }
```

And now to my problem with this solution: I want to define in the TreeStore, which actions should be done by the controller - especially which component should be loaded.

**For example I would like that the TreeStore looks like this:**

```
Ext.define('LT.store.MnuApplication', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
            text: "Lists", 
            expanded: true, 
            children: [{
                text: "Countries", 
                leaf: true,
                loadComponent: 'country-list',
                loadTarget: 'tabPanel'
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

As you can see I´ve added two new parameters to the Tree Leaf. Now I cann access those datasets via the "RAW" method of the record. But that´s not really a nice solution - isn´t it?

So has anyone an idea for me, how to pass additional parameters (like "loadComponent" or "loadTaget") from my TreeStore to the controller?

Thanks in advance & cheers,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

In the past I created similar tree with my custom parameters and I used a custom model for my TreeStore. Because by default your node, just has properties of NodeInterface. Something like this:

```
Ext.define('TreeConfig.model.Config', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['properties', 'id', 'text', 'guid'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: rootConfigURL,
        actionMethods: 'POST',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'            
        }
    }
});


Ext.define('TreeConfig.store.CurrentConfig', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    model: 'TreeConfig.model.Config',
    requires: 'TreeConfig.model.Config',    
    root: {
        text: 'Config root',
        expanded: true,
        properties: []        
    }
});
```

Comment: I've got a similar problem, so how would you then pass the guid of the node to the TreeStore proxy so that the next level of nodes is loaded based on the expanded node?

Comment: you should set idProperty in your model. Proxy will use this property when it makes a request.

Comment: do you know how you can pass additional arguments to the ajax proxy.  The idProperty is being passed as the node - can you specify others?